# How to show hidden div when javascript is disabled?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I'm hiding a `div` using `display:none` and this `div` only shows when we click on **+** icon. but if JavaScript is disabled then I want to show that `div` by default on. How to do this?

I can't post whole code for now.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('a#toggle').click(function() {
       jQuery('#map').slideToggle(400);
       return false;

});
```

CSS

```
#map {display:none}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if javascript is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098046/how-to-check-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Only hide it if Javascript is enabled:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.write('<style type="text/css" media="screen">#map { display: none; }</style>');
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I feel this is a better solution to the above 2, because the others will cause your page to flicker once it's loaded and all the divs are hidden with jQuery, if JS is enabled. I would suggest just including a different stylesheet in `<noscript></noscript>` tags that just overrides the default `display:none;` with `display:block;`

Comment: @strelok The problem being that `<noscript>` can't be used in the `<head>` (AFAIK).

Comment: You are correct. But yeah, either way, your solution is much better than using javascript to actually hide all the divs on page load.

Comment: working now I just added `document.write('<style type="text/css" media="screen">#map { display: none; }</style>');
' at top of my external javascript

Answer (score 3):

You could use a noscript tag:

```
<noscript>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">#map { display: block !important; }</style>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 2):

While rendering on server don't set `display:none` to that div. During page load on client set `display:none` using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

This would be a better idea that other

Put the division you want to show if the javascript is not enable inside `<noscript>` tags

Comment: If the javascript is disabled in the client, your external js will not work anyway